# SharePoint 2010 - Office Files opening in READ ONLY mode (Even with users having Contribute Permissions)

Tags: 2010, edit, read

I was wondering if somebody could offer me some advice.

I work in a major organisation and I look after our SharePoint 2010 site.

The issue were having is that sometimes, members of staff, where if they try to open files (mainly MS Office files) in document libraries, they are presented with the options to 'Open', 'Save' and 'Save As', however, most people (and this is what we want everybody to have), are presented with the options to open in 'Read Only' and 'Edit Mode'.

I've ensured those few members of staff do have Contribute permissions to edit files, however, the system of SharePoint isn't exactly useful to them if they can't open the files straight up in edit mode, for them to simply save edited documents/spreadsheets etc back into SharePoint 2010.

Those members of staff with the issue are having to save an edited document elsewhere on their systems, delete the copy saved in SharePoint and re-upload.

We use IE 11 by default. I've tried resetting IE 11 and repairing the Office 2013 suite. I can't seem to find a way to fix this without asking our IT department to do a complete Windows profile reset, which is a huge fix for such a minor, but frustrating issue.

I don't have access to the top administration level of SharePoint 2010, so I'd need to speak with my colleagues.

This is a very frustrating issue. Any advice  on how this can be fixed so everyone has the ability to open items in 'Edit mode' would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

David

EDIT: I forgot to mention, we have Office 2013.